# Could not find initializer for type 'TableCell' that accepts an argument list of type

Tags: swift, xcode6

XCODE: Swift

Full Error:

Could not find initializer for type `TableCell` that accepts an argument list of type `caseImage: (UIImge, caseName: String, caseDate: String)`

```
var patientCaseArray = [TableCell]()
func loadSampleData() {
    let Photo1 = UIImage(named: "retino1")!
    let case1 = TableCell(caseImage: Photo1, caseName: "John Smith", caseDate: "2015-10-18" )  
    //error
    patientCaseArray = [case1]
}
```

Working on a table cell class defined elsewhere, with this set of IBOutlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var caseImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var caseName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var caseDate: UILabel!
```

I haven't done anything to the class except add the outlets.

I'm very new to swift and I'm going through a tutorial which says this is supposed to compile fine. It isn't supposed to input to the table yet. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a discrepancy in types:

> Could not find initializer for type 'TableCell' that accepts an
>   argument list of type caseImage: '(**UIImge**, caseName: String,
>   caseDate: String)'

and

> @IBOutlet weak var caseImage: **UIImageView**!

UIImageView is not the same as UIImage, you will need to decide which one you want to use.